# Renaming URL on Umbraco back end content navigation in list views

Tags: umbraco

How do you change the URL that is generated for Umbraco back end "list view" content navigation?

For example, i would like:

https://localhost:44300/umbraco/#/content/content/edit/1?page=1

to become:

https://localhost:44300/MYURL/#/content/content/edit/1?page=1

Answer (score 0):

[Unofficial] There are 2 a web config values

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/" />
<add key="umbracoPath" value="~/umbraco" />
```

I changed mine to

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco2,~/install/" />
<add key="umbracoPath" value="~/umbraco2" />
```

and then changed the umbraco directory in the folder IIS is pointing to.

Now the backoffice seems to work with

> [host]/umbraco2